# Check if req.body is empty doesnt work with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, postman

I tried to test my login request in postman with an empty body but this check doesn't work. It goes beyond and execute the rest of the code. Why ?
Is there another way to check if body is empty ?

```
route.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  if (!req.body) {
    console.log("I am here");
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Content cannot be empty" });
    return;
  }
... // check password etc
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check how many keys req.body has

```
if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
    console.log("I am here");
    res.status(400).send({ message: "Content cannot be empty" });
    return;
}
```

Comment: It work with Object and not Objects, Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can check the length of the Body :`if (Objects.keys(req.body).length === 0) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

**`if(Object.keys(req.body).length === 0)`**

or
**`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(req.body).length == 0`**

then add your logic.